# Need to access helper variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, I have a helper called "Status Updates Helper" and one called "Meals Helper".

I need to access the variables in Status Updates Helper from within Meals Helper...

I've tried using "include StatusUpdatesHelper" inside my Meals Helper, although that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Meals Helper file:

```
module MealsHelper
 def total_of(macro)
 current_user.meal_foods.map(&macro).inject(:+)
end

def pct_fat_satisfied
   #how much of a macro is needed?
   #  fat_needed = fat factor * current lbm
   fat_factor = current_user.fat_factor
   current_lbm = current_user.status_update.first.current_lbm
   fat_needed = fat_factor * current_lbm
   #how much is in the meal?
   fat_provided = total_of(:fat)
   #percent needed
   pct_fulfilled = fat_provided.to_f/fat_needed.to_f
   return BigDecimal(pct_fulfilled, 2)*100
end     

def pct_carbs_satisfied( tdee, deficit_pct )
 #how many carbs are needed?
 cals_needed = tdee.to_f * (1 - deficit_pct.to_f)
 carbs_needed = cals_needed * 4
 #how many carbs are provided?
 carbs_provided = total_of(:carbs)
 #what is the pct satisfied?
 pct_fulfilled = carbs_provided.to_f/carbs_needed.to_f
 return tdee 
end  

def pct_protein_satisfied
  #how much protien is needed?
  protein_factor = current_user.protein_factor 
  current_lbm = current_user.status_update.first.current_lbm
  protein_needed = protein_factor * current_lbm
  #how much protien is provided?
  protein_provided = total_of(:protien)
  #pct of protien satisfied?
  pct_fulfilled = protein_provided.to_f/protein_needed.to_f
  return BigDecimal(pct_fulfilled, 2)*100
end

end
```

and here is the status updates helper file:

```
module StatusUpdatesHelper

def bmr(lbm) 
  lbm *= 0.45
  return '%.2f' % (370 + (21.6 * lbm.to_d))
end

def target_weight(total_weight, target_bf_pct, lbm)
 target_bf_pct /= 100
 return '%.2f' %  ((total_weight*target_bf_pct)+lbm)
end 

def fat_to_burn(total_weight, target_weight)
 return '%.2f' % (total_weight.to_d - target_weight.to_d)
end

def tdee(bmr, activity_factor)
  return '%.2f' % (bmr.to_d*activity_factor.to_d)
end

def deficit_pct(deficit_amnt, tdee)
 daily_cal_def = ((deficit_amnt.to_f * 3500)/7)
 return (daily_cal_def.to_d/tdee.to_d)
end

def daily_calorie_target(tdee, deficit_pct)
 return '%.2f' % (tdee.to_d * deficit_pct.to_d)  
end

def weekly_burn_rate(tdee, daily_calorie_target)
  return '%.2f' % (daily_calorie_target.to_d*7) 
end

def time_to_goal(weekly_burn_rate, fat_to_burn)
  return '%.2f' %  (fat_to_burn.to_d*3500/weekly_burn_rate.to_d) 
end                  

def daily_intake( tdee, daily_calorie_target )
  return '%.2f' % (tdee.to_d - daily_calorie_target.to_d)
end


def total_progress
 if user_signed_in?
   if current_user.status_update.empty?
    @total_weight_change   = 0
    @total_fat_change      = 0
    @total_lbm_change      = 0

    @time_to_goal          = 0
    @fat_to_burn           = 0
    @target_bf_pct         = 0
    @lbm                   = 0
    @activity_factor       = 0
    @bmr                   = 0
    @total_weight          = 0
    @target_weight         = 0
    @fat_to_burn           = 0
    @tdee                  = 0
    @deficit_amnt          = 0
    @deficit_pct           = 0
    @daily_calorie_target  = 0
    @daily_intake          = 0
    @weekly_burn_rate      = 0
    @time_to_goal          = 0

    @current_weight        = 0
    @current_bf_pct        = 0
    @current_lbm           = 0
    @current_fat_weight    = 0

    @daily_caloric_deficit = 0
  end

  if current_user.status_update.any?

    @first = current_user.status_update.first

    @last  = current_user.status_update.last

    @beginning_date       = current_user.status_update
                           .first.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    @last_date            = current_user.status_update
                           .last.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    @total_weight_change  = BigDecimal(@first.current_weight - 
                                       @last.current_weight, 3)
    @total_fat_change     = BigDecimal(@first.current_fat_weight - 
                                       @last.current_fat_weight, 3)
    @total_lbm_change     = BigDecimal(@first.current_lbm - 
                                       @last.current_lbm, 3)
    @recent_fat_change    = BigDecimal(@first.current_fat_weight -
                                       @first.previous_status_update.current_fat_weight, 3)
    @recent_lbm_change    = BigDecimal(@first.current_lbm -
                                       @first.previous_status_update.current_lbm, 2)
    @recent_weight_change = BigDecimal(@first.current_weight -
                                       @first.previous_status_update.current_weight, 2) 
    @lbm                  = @first.current_lbm
    @activity_factor      = current_user.activity_factor
    @bmr                  = bmr(@lbm)
    @total_weight         = @first.current_weight
    @target_bf_pct        = (current_user.target_bf_pct) 
    @target_weight        = target_weight(@total_weight, @target_bf_pct, @lbm)
    @fat_to_burn          = fat_to_burn(@total_weight, @target_weight)
    @tdee                 = tdee(@bmr, @activity_factor)
    @deficit_amnt         = current_user.deficit_amnt
    @deficit_pct          = deficit_pct(@deficit_amnt, @tdee)
    @daily_calorie_target = daily_calorie_target(@tdee, @deficit_pct)
    @daily_intake         = daily_intake(@tdee, @daily_calorie_target)
    @weekly_burn_rate     = weekly_burn_rate(@tdee, @daily_calorie_target)
    @time_to_goal         = time_to_goal(@weekly_burn_rate, @fat_to_burn)
    @current_weight       = BigDecimal(@first.current_weight, 4)
    @current_bf_pct       = BigDecimal(@first.current_bf_pct * 100, 4)
    @current_lbm          = BigDecimal(@first.current_lbm, 4)
    @current_fat_weight   = BigDecimal(@first.current_fat_weight, 4)
    @daily_caloric_deficit = @tdee.to_d - @daily_intake.to_d
    #End Date
    @start_date           = current_user.status_update.first.created_at
    @end_date             = (@start_date + @time_to_goal.to_i.weeks).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end           
 end
 end
 end
```

From within the meals show view, when I ask for the pct_carbs_fulfilled, it returns "infinity".

If I put "100" int he return part it will return "100".

The status updates helper works nicely.

I know this is not a restful strategy, so any suggestions on how to make it more restful would be very much appreciated.

So my question is, why is what I'm doing not working and how can I get these variables passed into the meals show view?

Here's a portion of the meals show view where the variables are being rendered

```
<td> <%= pct_fat_satisfied     %>% </td>
<td> <%= @tdee                 %>% </td>
<td> <%= pct_protein_satisfied %>% </td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What can I do to improve this question? It's gotten 21 views as of me writing this with no answers.

Comment: You are using helpers in a wrong way. I'm aware of the fact that this doesn't help you at all. My best advise: Try to solve more logic within a model's method. Use helpers only for displaying stuff.

Pretend for a moment that helpers don't exist.

Comment: Grr lol I had an intuition that I'd have to move these methods into a model. That's going to screw up a huge portion of my code. Oh well. I better get to it sooner than procrastinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed to move all this logic into the user model, so that's what I did.

I removed the entire "total_progress" method and made instance methods out of each variable within it.

Instead of trying to save all these variables in an object I found out that I could instead solve for any attribute with these methods using new data that is provided from other objects and the relatively static attributes that belong to the user.

This makes all these other 'calculated' variables more dynamic in that I never have to save them. every time the user updates other objects, these values update instantly since finding them requires the need to recalculate them every time.

I've found the incredible usefulness in placing as much logic as possible in the model while keep my controllers thin and my views absent of any logic as well.

It makes life 9,000,000,002,839,420,934,820,394 times easier.

So the moral of the story is "Use fat models and thin controllers".